# get selected text position in PDFBox

Tags: pdfbox

i am developing a translator app in android and i want to use PDFBox to manipulate pdf files.
one of my most challanges is:

1. i want to get selected text position when user reading a pdf book
   and select special word.
2. after that i want to create an annotation on position extract from
   step one.

the second problem is done by me.here is the code:

```
public static void setHighLightText(Integer i) {
        try {
            PDDocument pdfDocument = PDDocument.load(new File("/home/saeed/Documents/Book/installArch.pdf"));
            PDPage page = (PDPage) pdfDocument.getDocumentCatalog().getPages().get(i);
            List<PDAnnotation> annots = page.getAnnotations();
            PDAnnotationTextMarkup markup = new PDAnnotationTextMarkup(PDAnnotationTextMarkup.SUB_TYPE_STRIKEOUT);
            PDColor yellow = new PDColor(new float[] { 1, 1, 0 }, PDDeviceRGB.INSTANCE);
            markup.setColor(yellow);
            PDRectangle position = new PDRectangle();
            position.setLowerLeftX(50);
            position.setLowerLeftY(50);
            position.setUpperRightX(150);
            position.setUpperRightY(150);
            markup.setRectangle(position);

            float[] quads = new float[8];

            quads[0] = position.getLowerLeftX(); // x1
            quads[1] = position.getUpperRightY() - 2; // y1
            quads[2] = position.getUpperRightX(); // x2
            quads[3] = quads[1]; // y2
            quads[4] = quads[0]; // x3
            quads[5] = position.getLowerLeftY() - 2; // y3
            quads[6] = quads[2]; // x4
            quads[7] = quads[5]; // y5

            markup.setQuadPoints(quads);
            markup.setSubtype("Highlight");
            markup.setModifiedDate(Calendar.getInstance().getTime().toString());
            markup.setContents("Hi Saeed!");
            annots.add(markup);

            pdfDocument.save("/home/saeed/Documents/Book/installArch.pdf");
            System.out.println("Text Added Successfully!!!");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

but my primary question is that, how can i extract current position of selectd word in pdf with PDFBox?
thanks in advance.

Comment: Please have a look at the ExtractTextByArea example in the non android source code download.

Comment: *how can i extract current position of selectd word in pdf with PDFBox* - PDFBox does not display the PDF or other wise allow the user to "select a word" in the PDF. Thus, the answer must be "There is no selected word in the PDF PDFBox sees."

Comment: @mkl Isnt isnt it possible to get the location of the text in pdf by including javascript and then annotate on clicked location?

Comment: @analyticalpicasso *"Isnt isnt it possible to get the location of the text in pdf by including javascript and then annotate on clicked location?"* - Probably. (I don't really deal with JavaScript or the Acrobat JavaScript API. And I don't know whether JavaScript in general or this API in particular is available on the Android PDF viewer the OP uses.) But that's not what the question is about, the OP wanted to "get selected text position in PDFBox" and not some PDF viewer using JavaScript APIs.

Comment: @mkl Ok. Sure. Thanks for your quick response :)